# C++11 Setter function parameter passing nullptr

Tags: c++, c++11, parameter-passing, setter, nullptr

I was wondering about C++11 best practices regarding parameter passing nullptr.  I want to reset a class member object by passing a nullptr to an already existing setter function.  For a simple example:

```
#include "foo.h"

Foo my_foo;

void set_foo(std::shared_ptr<Foo> bar){
  my_foo = bar;
}

int main()
{
  set_foo(std::make_shared<Foo>());
  //do stuff
  set_foo(nullptr);
}
```

Is this okay?  Or, or are there better, more preferred methods for resetting my_foo?  I didn't want to make another method just for resetting my_foo.

The real motivation in the application I'm working on is that I have a persisting singleton class that is shared by a variable number of other classes.  It's convenient for coding purposes for those other classes to simply own a shared pointer to that singleton for the duration they require and use it, and then to discard/set to nullptr when they are no longer allowed to have access to it.  If there's anything I may be missing or not thinking of, any advice is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Any advice? Get rid of that singleton!

Comment: I think it's acceptable and you can find examples of it in the C++ standard library (e.g. `std::unqiue_ptr::reset()`).

Answer (score 0):

While there are many different paradigms you can use with C++, you can use *methods* to bundle data and operations together?

But you probably don't want to change the `Foo` interface, so I am guessing you want to implement something like the *Singleton pattern*, with an additional functionality for destroying it?

I would prefer two different functions in that case. When you have two functions with different names it is a better way for "making the interface easy to use correctly and hard to use incorrectly" (sic. see Scott Meyers). If you hide a functionality in a function that does not fit its name, that makes it "hard", in that sense.

This would translate to

```
#include "foo.h"

Foo my_foo;

void set_foo(std::shared_ptr<Foo> bar){
    my_foo = bar;
}

void clear_foo(){
    my_foo = nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo.set(std::make_shared<Foo>());
    //do stuff
    clear_foo();
}
```

...although I am not quite sure what you mean with assigning `shared_ptr<Foo>` to a `Foo` with `operator` in `set_foo`, I just used your code here.

I would be more comfortable using a wrapper that can handle your set- and clear-features.
And from starting here I would even go so far and use *Resource Acquisition Is Initialization* (RAII), which you could introduce here like this (sketch only):

```
#include "foo.h"

struct FooWrapper {
    shared_ptr<Foo> bar_;
    FooWrapper() : bar_(nullptr) {}
    FooWrapper(shared_ptr<Foo> bar) : bar_(bar) {}
    void set(shared_ptr bar<Foo> bar) { bar_ = bar; }
    void clear() { bar = nullptr; }        
    Foo* operator->() { return bar_.get(); }
};

FooWrapper my_foo{};

int main()
{
    my_foo.set(std::make_shared<Foo>()); // 1
    my_foo->do_stuff();
    my_foo.clear(); // clear
    my_foo.set(std::make_shared<Foo>()); // 2
} // forgot to clear, doesn't matter FooWrapper takes care of that.
```

I guess you can dispense with the whole `FooWrapper` though, and just use the a global `shared_ptr<Foo> foo`.

```
#include "foo.h"

shared_ptr<Foo> my_foo{nullptr};

int main()
{
    my_foo.reset( new Foo{} ); // 1
    my_foo->do_stuff();
    my_foo.reset( new Foo{} ); // 2
    my_foo.reset(nullptr);     // clear
}
```

As you can see, `shared_ptr` uses the pattern to bundle two different functionalities into the `reset`-method. So, it cant be totally bad.